# How to serve video file / stream from ASP Net Core 6 Minimal API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I was trying to achieve this following different tutorials but did not succeed. How do I handle a http range request in minimal API to serve video stream ?

I have this bare minimal setup code for API with a single GET path "/video" mapped. I also made a folder "wwwroot" inside project folder. I placed in there a mp4 video file named "test.mp4". Would it be possible for someone knowledgeable to write a simple example of how to stream this file inside my mapped route ?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
 var app = builder.Build();
    
 if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
     builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI();
 }
    
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
 app.MapGet("/video", () =>
 {    
    
    
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Results.Stream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.stream?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method to return a stream from a minimal api.

```cs
string wwwroot = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;
...
app.MapGet("/video", () =>
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(wwwroot, "test.mp4");
    return Results.Stream(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
});
```

> The stream parameter is disposed after the response is sent.

`Results.Stream` takes a few other optional parameters such as `fileDownloadName`, and `contentType` (which defaults to `"application/octet-stream"`) that might be useful to you.  Set `enableRangeProcessing: true` to enable [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

The above could easily be adapted to take a `filename` as a parameter, if you wish. You would need to consider validation (applies equally to the current code TBH). Tested and working for me.